# Value is returning null even after setstate() flutter stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to access the value of a String after updating it using setState() but it returns null when passValues() function is called.

Here is the code

Class 1

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 void main() {
 runApp(const TheOptions());
}

class TheOptions extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return: ElevatedButton.icon(
      onPressed: () {
        _Options().passValues();
      },
```

Class 2

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//.... several other imports that does not matters as they irrelevant to question

class _Options extends State<Options> {
String? selectedValue;

void splitType(String? newValue) {
    setState(() {
      selectedValue = newValue!;
 });
  }

void passValues()
{
log(selectedValue.toString());// this returns null.
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
              value: selectedValue,
              hint: Container(
                child: Text("Split By"),
              ),
              isExpanded: true,
              iconSize: 32,
              onChanged: splitType,
              items: [

DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Value 1"), value: "value_1"),
DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Value 2"), value: "value_2")
]),
        ),
}}
```

Console Output

```
[log] null
```

It maybe done using provider or key but unable to figure it out. What is the best way to do it?

Expecting the new updated value to be printed in log.

Comment: Your code is not well-formatted and you do not show where are you calling `passValues`. Please edit your post including this information.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I was trying to give only the code that matters but anyhow the code is updated.

Comment: What does `log(selectedValue.toString());` do?

Comment: `log(selectedValue.toString());`  is used for testing purpose to check if the value is updated.

Comment: Can you post the imports on that page or the error output in the console?

Comment: Where is `TheOptions` widget used?

Comment: `TheOptions` used inside another class to show button but I am pretty sure it does not matters.

Comment: It's not clear where `TheOptions` class' button is in the tree. Maybe a minimal reproducible example can help to wards a solution. However, calling `_Options()` class looks like it instantiates a new instance of the class, where `selectedValue` is null by default.

Comment: Please include where `_Options` is displayed on the screen. You can access the value in `_Options` using a callback passed to it provided `TheOptions` has access to it.